# Spyder kernel crashes and restart when using np.maximum function

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Spyder with python 3.7 under anaconda since early June (I'm a newbee ;-) )
For the first time since I started using python, Spyder kernel crashed three times, systematically when I use the np.maximum function `trRange = np.maximum((dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['low']) , abs(dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1)), abs(dataTrad['low'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1)))`

I then tried to define `(dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['low'])` as tr1, `abs(dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))`as tr2 and `abs(dataTrad['low'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))`and to compute the np.maximum(tr1, tr2, tr3), I get the same result : `

> [IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 67d34c4cb65e11ea9afb7440bb3a6582

Is there something wrong with my code, or is there an issue with numpy np.maximum() function ?
I first use the max() function but I got an error messagethe Truth value is ambiguous...
Thanks for your help ;-)

`

Comment: what is the `shape` and `dtype` of tr1 tr2,tr3?

Comment: All 3 are Series(60k, ) containing float64 objects